# How to create dynamic time intervals in SQL Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a query that should recognize the dates when different budgets associated to one account were totally consumed. My start date is 1/12 so my task is to create a cumulative sum of the expenses that the account made for its first budget, then when the cumulative sum reach the budget, I should store the date when it happened, and the use that date as my new START DATE to compute the expenses of the same account but for the second budget, and so on. It seems for me difficult to create this dynamic interval was on the result of the previous budget. Do you have any idea of how I could I manage this problem?

**What I Tried**

```
WITH TRM_INTERVAL AS 
    (
    SELECT 
    Country,
    replace(Account_ID, '-', '') AS fixed_accountid,
    TO_DATE(Date) AS CONVERTED_DATE,
    TO_DATE(CAST(CONVERTED_DATE AS VARCHAR), 'YYYY-DD-MM') AS CONVERTED_DATE_FORMAT,
    TRM2,
    TRM1,
    TOTAL_ARS_IN_ACCOUNT,
    row_number()
    over (partition by Account_ID, Country order by CONVERTED_DATE_FORMAT) AS ROW_NUMBER,
    lag(TOTAL_ARS_IN_ACCOUNT)
    over (partition by Account_ID, Country order by CONVERTED_DATE_FORMAT) AS PREVIOUS_ARS_BUCKET,
    lead(CONVERTED_DATE_FORMAT)
    over (partition by Account_ID, Country order by CONVERTED_DATE_FORMAT) AS NEXT_DATE
    FROM CONECTOR
),

--DETAIL
DETAIL AS (

    SELECT TI.COUNTRY, TI.fixed_accountid, TI.PREVIOUS_ARS_BUCKET, TI.TOTAL_ARS_IN_ACCOUNT, TI.ROW_NUMBER, GO.EVENT_DATE, SUM(CASE WHEN GO.CURRENCY_ORIGINAL = 'ARS' THEN GO.FINAL_CAC * 160 END) AS ARS_SPEND,
    
    SUM(ARS_SPEND) OVER(PARTITION BY TI.fixed_accountid, TI.COUNTRY, TI.TOTAL_ARS_IN_ACCOUNT ORDER BY GO.EVENT_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CUMULATIVE_ARS_SPEND
    
    FROM TABLE1 AS GO
    JOIN CONECTOR AS TI
    ON GO.ACCOUNT_ID = TI.fixed_accountid AND GO.COUNTRY = TI.COUNTRY
    WHERE GO.EVENT_DATE >= '2022-12-1'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

),


--ACUMULADO
LOGIC AS (
    
    SELECT *,
    CUMULATIVE_ARS_SPEND / TOTAL_ARS_IN_ACCOUNT AS CUMULATIVE_ARS_SPEND_PERCENTAGE,
    --COMO VALIDAR CON EL TI TOTAL ARS CORRESPONDIENTE
    CASE WHEN CUMULATIVE_ARS_SPEND_PERCENTAGE >=0.686 AND EVENT_DATE <> CURRENT_DATE() THEN 'FLAG' END AS FLAGS  
    
    
    FROM DETAIL

)
```

I have 3 subqueries. To sum up, I create the cumulative sum of the expenses related to each account but I could not create the dynamic intervals. The dates start from 12/1/2022.

**What actually resulted**

You see 3 budgets as example. All of them are associated with a single account. I start with the budget 500,000, you see that I made the cumulative sum until it reach 100%. but then for the second budget 30,000,000 the dates and the expenses are repeated. The same dates were applied 1/12, 1/13, 1/14 and 1/15. The idea is that if the first budget was totally consumed on 1/15 as you can see, the query should compute the expenses for the second budget since one day later 1/16 until that second budget is as well totally consumed and so on.

```
FECHA   BUDGET      SPEND_DAILY     CUMULATIVE   % ACUMM
01/12/2022  500000    100000        100000       20.00%
01/13/2022  500000    150000        250000       50.00%
01/14/2022  500000    200000        450000       90.00%
01/15/2022  500000    50000         500000       100.00%
01/12/2022  30000000  100000        100000         0.33%
01/13/2022  30000000  150000        250000         0.83%
01/14/2022  30000000  200000        450000         1.50%
01/15/2022  30000000  50000         500000         1.67%
01/12/2022  4000000   100000        100000        2.50%
01/13/2022  4000000   150000        250000        6.25%
01/14/2022  4000000   200000        450000        11.25%
01/15/2022  4000000   50000         500000        12.50%
```

**What I expected to happen**
The desire output should be these table, where the first budget is totally consumed one day, and on the next day, the expenses compute is updated and now the cumulative sum is applied to the second budget.

```
FECHA       BUDGET  GASTO DIARIO    GASTO ACUMM % ACUMM
01/12/2022  500000     100000            100000   20.00%
01/13/2022  500000     150000            250000   50.00%
01/14/2022  500000     200000            450000   90.00%
01/15/2022  500000     50000             500000   100.00%
01/16/2022  30000000    100000           100000     0.33%
01/17/2022  30000000    200000           300000     1.00%
01/18/2022  30000000    500000           800000     2.67%
01/19/2022  30000000    300000           1100000    3.67%
01/20/2022  30000000    150000           1250000    4.17%
01/21/2022  30000000    20000000         21250000   70.83%
01/22/2022  30000000    10000000         31250000   104.17%
```

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: @NickW thanks for the advice. I' ve just replaced the images with tables. It will be pretty valuable some help with this.